# View#findViewById returns null in runtime but not null in debugger

Tags: java, android

I've a very weird behavior in my android project.

First of all I created a custom view called ANumberPicker (to use it on Android devices with OS version < 3.0). Here is a code snippet of class:

```
public class ANumberPicker extends LinearLayout {


    // ...


    @NotNull
    private final NumberPickerButton incrementButton;

    @NotNull
    private final NumberPickerButton decrementButton;

    public ANumberPicker(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setOrientation(VERTICAL);

        // INFLATING LAYOUT
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_picker, this, true);

        final InputFilter inputFilter = new NumberPickerInputFilter();
        numberInputFilter = new NumberRangeKeyListener();

        incrementButton = (NumberPickerButton) this.findViewById(R.id.increment);
        incrementButton.setNumberPicker(this);

        decrementButton = (NumberPickerButton) this.findViewById(R.id.decrement);
        decrementButton.setNumberPicker(this);

        // ...
   }

   // ...

}
```

Here is the number_picker.xml layout:

```
<merge xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<org.solovyev.android.view.NumberPickerButton
        a:id="@+id/increment"
        a:layout_width="fill_parent"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:background="@drawable/timepicker_up_btn"/>

<EditText a:id="@+id/timepicker_input"
          a:layout_width="fill_parent"
          a:layout_height="wrap_content"
          a:gravity="center"
          a:singleLine="true"
          style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
          a:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
          a:textSize="30sp"
          a:inputType="numberDecimal"
          a:background="@drawable/timepicker_input"/>

<org.solovyev.android.view.NumberPickerButton
        a:id="@+id/decrement"
        a:layout_width="fill_parent"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:background="@drawable/timepicker_down_btn"/>
```

In ANumberPicker constructor I inflate 'number_picker.xml' layout and try to get view by id: inflater is used with attachToRoot = 'true' parameter. But I've got a NullPointerException in runtime on this line:

```
incrementButton.setNumberPicker(this);
```

i.e. incrementButton = null.

Furthermore debugging this code in Jetbrains IDEA I got next values in 'Watches' window (the breakpoint is set on the source line with NPE):

```
(NumberPickerButton) this.findViewById(R.id.increment) = {org.solovyev.android.view.NumberPickerButton@830082344688}
R.id.increment = 2131296256
this.getChildAt(0).getId() = 2131296256
incrementButton = null
```

i.e. exactly the same code returns not null in debugger.
And I can't figure it out... Is there any suggestions? Where might be the problem?

PS I cleaned the project and rebuilt it (I use maven)

EDIT
I found the clue: R.id.increment and view  have different integer identifiers (I just logged their ids in Logcat). But the problem persists - cleaning the project doesn't help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: Jetbrains IDEA stores in cache previously built R files, so "Invalidate caches" fixed the problem.